# Canceling/aborting a fetch request from a class outside the request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http

I'm trying to abort the controller inside this request. The request is in a function which is in a separate file. I then call this function from my class A:

```
export default async function getInfoReq({zon, mc, pc}) {
  let url = '/getInfo';
  let controller;
  let options = {
    method: "POST",
          headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            "o": zon,
            "m": mc,
            "p": pc
          })
  }
  const fetchData = async (retries) => {
    controller = new AbortController();
    const optionsWithSignal = {
      ...options,
      signal: controller.signal
    };

    try {
      let timer = setTimeout(() => controller.abort(), 5000)
      let response = await fetch(url, optionsWithSignal)
      clearTimeout(timer);
      if(response.ok) return response.json()
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
      if(retries === 1 || retries < 1) {
        return {
          message: "something went wrong"
        }
      }
      return await fetchData(retries - 1)
    } 
  };
    return await fetchData(2); 
}
```

And class A, in which i render a button and the UI and call the function to do a POST request.

```
...
let jsonString = await getInfoReq({zon: o, mc: mc, pc: pc})
...
render() {
...
<Button onClick={/* call controller.abort on the getInfoReq */}>CANCEL</Button>
...
}
```

How can I achieve aborting the fetch request from my class?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an object with controller property. This property will fulfilled inside the fetchData and exposed to the caller thru cntrl parameter

```
let cntrl = {controller}
let jsonString = await getInfoReq({zon: o, mc: mc, pc: pc}, cntrl)

abortBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
   cntrl.controller.abort();
})


//and modify the file:
export default async function getInfoReq({zon, mc, pc}, cntrl) {
...
  const fetchData = async (retries) => {
    controller = new AbortController();
    cntrl.controller = controller 
....
```